# Conceptual understanding of the effects of time shift on the coefficients of a Fourier Series.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, fourier-series

I have a function of a triangle wave that goes from a minimum value of 0 volts to a maximum value of V. It has a period of T, and is a maximum at t = 0. I'm trying to understand how a time shift $\tau$ would affect the coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ of the Fourier series.

Without a time shift I can write:

$$a_n = \frac 2T \int_{-\frac T2}^0 f(t) \cos(\frac {2\pi nt}{T})\,dt\ + \frac 2T \int_{0}^{\frac T2}g(t) \cos(\frac {2\pi nt}{T})\,dt$$

But once a time shift is introduced I have:

$$a_n(\tau) = \frac 2T \int_{-\frac T2}^0 f(t +\tau) \cos(\frac {2\pi nt}{T})\,dt\ + \frac 2T \int_{0}^{\frac T2} g(t+ \tau) \cos(\frac {2\pi nt}{T})\,dt$$

My assumption is that this adds an extra few terms to the oringinal $a_n$ such that $a_n(\tau) = a_n + C$, where C depends on n. Is this statement accurate?

Thinking of the coefficients as a projection of $f(t)$ onto the vector $\cos(n\omega t)$, I don't understand why shifting the graph would change the value of this projection for a given point on the function. Why is this?

Maybe I'm thinking of this all wrong or making wrong assumptions, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Food for thought: Since the projection can be used to reproduce the original graph, shifting the graph had better change the values of the projections to reflect the change in the graph.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand you. So the graph is a sum of projections of f(t) on cosine for all integers of n. To shift the graph is to shift where each projection lies on the plane. So the additional constant takes care of this and shifts the projections to the correct spot?

Comment: The new coefficients will not be related to the old ones in the way that you assumed: $a_n + C$. It will look more like the sum of angle formulas for sine and cosine.

Comment: I've posted an answer, let me know if it sufficiently answers your question.

Comment: If $f(t)= \sum_n c_n e^{2i \pi nt/T}$ then $f(t+\tau) = \sum_n c_n e^{2i\pi n\tau/T} e^{2i\pi nt/T}$. Note the complex exponentials are the eigenfunctions of the shift operator, those with $2\pi n/T$ frequency are the $T$-periodic eigenfunctions. The $\cos,\sin$ expansion makes it much less readable (thus you should avoid it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f(t)$ is a periodic function with period $T$.

The fourier series of $f$ is,

$$ f(t) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big[a_n \cos(n\omega t) + b_n \sin(n\omega t)\Big]$$

Where

$$ a_0 = \frac1T \int_0^T f(t) \mathrm{d}t$$
$$ a_n = \frac2T \int_0^T f(t) \cos(n\omega t)\mathrm{d}t$$
$$ b_n = \frac2T \int_0^T f(t) \sin(n\omega t)\mathrm{d}t$$
$$ \omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$$

---

Now lets study the effect of a shift in $t$ by an amount $\tau$ on the Fourier coefficients of $f$. We could study this by analyzing the integral expressions for the coefficients, but it is easier to study it by manipulating the Fourier series term by term.

$$ f(t+\tau) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big[a_n \cos\Big(n\omega (t+\tau)\Big) + b_n \sin\Big(n\omega (t+\tau)\Big)\Big]$$

$$ = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big[a_n \cos(n\omega t+n\omega\tau) + b_n \sin(n\omega t+ n\omega\tau)\Big]$$

$$ = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big[a_n \Big(\cos(n\omega t)\cos(n\omega\tau) - \sin(n\omega t)\sin(n \omega \tau) \Big) + b_n \Big( \sin(n\omega t)\cos(n\omega\tau) + \cos(n\omega t) \sin(n\omega\tau)\Big)\Big]$$

Collecting the coefficients of $\cos(n\omega t)$ and $\sin(n\omega t)$ together we get,

$$ = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big[\Big(\color{blue}{ a_n \cos(n\omega\tau) + b_n \sin(n\omega\tau)} \Big) \cos(n\omega t) + \Big(\color{blue}{b_n \cos(n\omega\tau)-a_n \sin(n\omega\tau) }\Big) \sin(n\omega t) \Big]$$

The blue expressions are the new coefficients, lets call them $a_n'$ and $b_n'$

$$ = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big[\color{blue}{ a_n'}  \cos(n\omega t) + \color{blue}{b_n'}\sin(n\omega t) \Big]$$

Note that the coefficient $a_0$ remains unchanged.

The transformation rule is, 
$$ a_0 \rightarrow a_0$$
$$ a_n \rightarrow a_n \cos(n\omega\tau) + b_n \sin(n\omega\tau) \qquad (n\geq 1)$$
$$ b_n \rightarrow b_n \cos(n\omega\tau)-a_n \sin(n\omega\tau)$$

---

Note that these coefficients transform exactly as if they were the $x$ and $y$ components of a vector being rotated in the $xy$ plane by an angle $n\omega\tau$.

Comment: Thank you!! It's interesting that you can get then new coefficients by treating $a_n$ and $b_n$ as components of a vector and then multiplying by the rotation matrix. This gives me plenty to think about!